# There are no errors but when I run it, it shows a white screen

Tags: python

I made a pretty big code using trinket.io. Later I made a shop, then a save feature. Once, I made a save feature the code stopped working.

I've tried fixing the indents fixing spelling errors putting the code into new 
python programs.

```
def main():
  reward = 0
  patt = 20 
  pdef = 10
  php = 35
  pgold= 0
  pgold = pgold + reward
  name = input("what is your name")
  print('''You are ''' +name+ ''' and you're trying to escape from the zoo but OUTTA NOWHERE A...''')
  save()

  def save():
    import random
    import time

    name = input("what is your name")
    print('''You are ''' +name+ ''' and you're trying to escape from the zoo but OUTTA NOWHERE A...''')

    number1 = random.randint(1,7)
    if number1 == 1:
        spawn = ' Monkey God'
        satt = 1000
        sdef = 9999
        shp = 1000000

    elif number1 == 2:
        spawn = ' Howard the alien'
        satt = 0
        sdef = 1
        shp = 1

    elif number1 == 3:
        spawn = ' Evan'
        satt = random.randint(4,21)
        sdef = random.randint(21,99)
        shp = random.randint(1,50)

    elif number1 == 4:
        spawn = ' Game Katana'
        satt = random.randint(1,500)
        sdef = random.randint(4,25)
        shp = random.randint(5,25)

    elif number1 == 5:
        spawn = ' John Cena'
        satt = 50
        sdef = random.randint(1,42)
        shp = 25

    elif number1 == 6:
        spawn = ' Willy Wonka'
        satt = random.randint(1,50)
        sdef = random.randint(1,50)
        shp = random.randint(1,50)
    else:
        spawn = ' Jax'
        satt = random.randint(1,25)
        sdef = random.randint(1,25)
        shp = random.randint(1,25)

    number2 = random.randint(1,4)
    if number2 == 1:
        adj = 'cringey'
        satt = satt -25

    elif number2 == 2:
        adj = 'OP'
        sdef = sdef +40

    elif number2 == 3:
        adj = 'demonic'
        shp = shp +30

    else:
        adj = 'angelic'
        sdef = sdef +3
    print ('random ' +adj + spawn+ ' appeared!')

    while php >0 and shp >0:
        choice = ('z')
        while choice != ('a'):
            print ('What u gonna do')
            print ('    a) Fight you strong man or woman')
            print ('    b) Run away because you are soooo scared that you do not want to fight')
            print ('    c) Look at dem stats booooiiii')
            choice = input()
            if choice == ('a'):
                print('You attack like a man (or woman)')
            if choice == ('b'):
                print ('you run away')
                print ('nevermind the ' +adj + spawn+ ' eats like you like a very hungry guy at McDonalds ' )
                php =0
                break
            if choice == ('c'):
                print('your own stats boooiiii')
                print('Attack = ' +str(patt)+ '   Defense = ' +str(pdef)+ '  Health = ' +str(php)+ '  Gold = ' +str(pgold) )
                print(adj + spawn+ '''\'s stats''')
                print('Attack = ' +str(satt)+ '   Defense = ' +str(sdef)+ '   Health = ' +str(shp) )
            if choice ==('a'):
                pattroll = random.randint(1,50)
                if pattroll >= sdef:
                    damage = random.randint(1,50)
                    print('You attack the  ' +adj + spawn+ ' and according to my calculations you did ' +str(damage)+ '!')
                    shp = shp - damage
                if pattroll < sdef:
                  print('you miss')
                  if shp >0:
                    sattroll = random.randint(1,50)
                    if sattroll >= pdef:
                        damage = random.randint (1,50)
                        print(' the' +adj + spawn+ ' hits you with ' +str(damage)+ '!')
                        php = php - damage
                    if sattroll < pdef:
                        print('You avoid being hit')
            if php <=0:
               print('You have died from ' +adj + spawn+ ' but, its a game so you will respawn if you click Run at the top of the screen')
            if shp <=0:
                reward = random.randint(30, 400)
                print('You win!!! you find ' +str(reward)+ ' Pieces of gold')
                pgold = pgold + reward
                php = 20
                print('You go to the hospital to heal')

    if php > 0:
      stock={'shield':1,
      'godly sword':1,
      'health pack':1,
      'wood sword':1,}
      prices={'shield': 10,
      'godly sword':4050,
      'health pack':1.5,
      'wood sword':3}

      def uppercase(x):
        return x[0].upper()+x[1:]


      print('Hi, %s, welcome to my store. Here is the menu:'%(name))
      print()

      def menu():
        for supplies in prices:
          print(uppercase(supplies))
          print('Price: $%s'%(prices[supplies]))
          print('Stock: %s'%(stock[supplies]))
        print('You have: $%s'%(pgold))

      def ask_supplies(pgold):
        supplies=input('''What do you want?
      ''')
        if supplies == ('shield'):
          php + 20
          print('your hp is now {php}')
        elif supplies == ('godly sword'):
          patt + 50
          print('your attack is now {patt}')
        elif supplies == ('health pack'):
          php + 5
          print('your hp is now {php}')
        else:
          patt + 10
          print('your attack is now {patt}')
        print()
        if supplies in stock:
          if stock[supplies]>0:
            ask_amount(supplies,pgold)
          else:
            print('''Sorry, %ss are out of stock
      '''%(supplies))
            ask_supplies(pgold)
        else:
          print('''Sorry, we don\'t have that, look at the menu.
          ''')
          ask_supplies(pgold)

      def ask_amount(supplies,pgold):
        amount=int(input('''How many %ss do you want?
      '''%(supplies)))
        print()
        if amount<=0:
          print('''At least buy one.
        ''')
          ask_amount(supplies,pgold)
        elif stock[supplies]>=amount:
          sell(supplies,amount,pgold)
        else:
          print('''Sorry, we don\'t have that many %ss.
          '''%(supplies))
          ask_amount(supplies,pgold)

      def sell(supplies,amount,pgold):
        cost=prices[supplies]*amount
        confirmation=input('''Are you sure? That will be $%s.
      -Yes
      -No
      '''%(cost)).lower()
        print()
        if confirmation=='yes':
          pgold-=cost
          print('''Thank you for shopping at Publix
      ''') 
          stock[supplies]=stock[supplies]-amount
          ask_again()
        elif confirmation=='no':
          ask_supplies()
        else:
          print('''Answer me.
      ''')
          sell(supplies,amount,pgold)

      def ask_again():
        answer=input('''Do you want anything else?
      -Yes
      -No
      ''').lower()
        print()
        if answer=='yes':
          menu()
          ask_supplies(pgold)
        elif answer=='no':
          print('Okay, bye.')
        else:
          print('Answer me.')
          ask_again()

      menu()
      ask_supplies(pgold)
      asksave = input('do you want to save and start again (Y/N)')
      if asksave == 'yes' or 'y':
        save()
      elif asksave == 'no' or 'n':
        restart=input("Do you want to play again?").lower()
        if restart == "yes" or "y":
          pgold = pgold + reward
          time.sleep(.3)
          main()

        else:
          exit()
```

I expect for the code to run and show something even if it is glitchy i can fix that but, I want to work.(also i'm really, really bad at coding. So take that in mind.)

Comment: Apart from having multiple `main` functions, you are not calling even one.

Comment: Even if the indents are correct, you're not calling any function.

Comment: should the `main` function be indented?

Comment: What do you mean by calling a function? @Jan

Comment: @EvanDragoje: See DirtyBits or my answer below.

Comment: Evan: Calling a function executes the code in its definition. For example: `main()` and `save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other problems / indentations you're not calling any function.
You could put the following code at the end of your file and see if that works (or shows any errors):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks worked its just that when I run it I want to add a save feature without using import pickle but I can't i cant go from line 8 to line 10 using save(). Because if I start from the beginning the new health the player has lost/gained etc. will be changed back to the original health, defence, attack, etc. Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling any function at all, considering you have properly indented your code, without replicated funciton names, this is how your ending script should look like

```
def main():
    # your  code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```